# How to get %APPDATA% path in C (windows 7)

Tags: c, windows, appdata

I need to get the path of %APPDATA% in my c program, to save a file in
`%APPDATA%\myprogram\` How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get that information through `getenv`, here is an example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char * app_data;
    app_data= getenv ("APPDATA");

    if (app_data!=NULL)
        printf ("The appdata path is: %s",app_data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That answers the OPs question (and will work almost all of the time) but is **not** the right way to do this.  The OP should instead use SHGetKnownFolderPath.

Comment: Can you give an example of using SHGetKnownFolderPath in C (because All I can find on that is in C++)